# Slack keyboard shortcut to toggle active / away

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, slack

I am looking for the keyboard shortcut in Slack macOS app to toggle `active` and `away`. 
I could not find it here, for example:
Slack keyboard shortcuts: https://slack.com/help/articles/201374536-Slack-keyboard-shortcuts

My current 2 workarounds (both are too long to be called "*short*cuts" proper):

- In the left panel, click on my name | Do not disturb | Set yourself *away* **or** Set yourself to *active*
- In the message window, type: `/away` **or** `/active`, <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
  Either of these toggle between `away` and `active`. This is described, for example, here:
  Set your Slack status and availability: https://slack.com/help/articles/201864558-Set-your-Slack-status-and-availability
  Use built-in slash commands: https://slack.com/help/articles/201259356-Use-built-in-slash-commands

Comment: Why are you giggling away/active so often? If you’re truly away, you would quit the app. If you’re active but don’t want to be disturbed, you would turn on do not disturb.

Comment: I prefer to toggle away/active since that is the exact status I am actually in. It reflects reality. I prefer to keep the app open rather than quit it since this way I can occasionally peek at the messages even when I am mostly away.

Comment: This would be really useful - I currently have a macro keypad set to type out the whole slash command, but a simple key shortcut toggle would be much simpler.

Comment: Wish there was an easy way to set active/away/inactive. I sometimes get up for 20 or 30 min to eat something but leave the computer on/unlocked and I'd like to signal I'm not actually here or paying attention.